# C++: Values of both objects changes after a Copy Constructor

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, copy-constructor

I have written a simple c++ code to understand the concepts of Copy Constructor/Operator Overloading. A snippet of the code is shown below.

In the code I am creating an object `vec v2` and then creating a new object `v4` and assign `vec v2`. Next I called the overloaded `operator[]` to change the values of `v4[0]` and `v4[1]`.

My issue is that after assigning these values, the values of `vec v2` has also changed.
I am not quite sure how this could have happened. Hope anyone can help me with this.

```
class vec {
private:
    // Variable to store the number of elements contained in this vec.
    size_t elements;
    // Pointer to store the address of the dynamically allocated memory.
    double* data;

public:

    vec(size_t size) : elements{ size }, data{ new double[size] } {std::cout << "First constructor" << "\n"; };
    
    vec(size_t size, double ival) : elements{ size }, data{ new double[size] } {
        std::cout << "Second constructor" << std::endl;
        for (int i = 0; i < elements; i++) {
            data[i] = ival;
        }
    }
    
    vec(std::initializer_list<double> iList): vec(static_cast<size_t>(iList.size())) {
        std::cout << "Third constructor" << std::endl;
        auto count{ 0 };

        for (auto element: iList) {
            data[count] = element;
            count++;
        }
    
    }
    
    /// Copy constructor that creates a copy of the vec variable 'v'.
    vec(const vec& v) : elements{ v.elements }, data{ new double[v.elements] }{
        std::cout << "Copy constructor " << "\n";
        std::memcpy(&data, &(v.data), v.elements);
    }
    
    /// Copy assignment operator. Creates a copy of vec variable 'v'.
    vec& operator=(const vec& v) {
        std::cout << "Copy assignment " << "\n";
        if (this != &v) {
            const auto new_data{ new double[v.elements] };
            delete[] data;

            data = new_data;
            elements = v.elements;
            std::memcpy(&data, &(v.data), v.elements);
        }
        return *this;
    }
    
    double& operator[](size_t idx){
        return this->data[idx];
    }
    
    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const vec& v) {

        for (int i = 0; i < v.elements; i++) {
            os << v.data[i] << "\n";
        }

        return os;
    }
};

int main(void) {

vec v2 = {4, 5, 6};
vec v4 = v2

v4[0] = 11;                                          // call to operator[]
v4[1] = 12;                                          // call to operator[]

return 0;
}
```

Comment: Pro tip: there's never a valid reason to use `memcpy` in pure C++ code. The shown call to `memcpy()` doesn't really do what you think it does.

Comment: `std::memcpy(&data, &(v.data), v.elements);` -- Use `std::copy`, not `std::memcpy` -- read the documentation of `std::memcpy` carefully, as that last parameter is wrong.  Also, if that were a vector of `std::string`, using `std::memcpy` would absolutely not work correctly, even with a "correction" of the last parameter.

Comment: And that's why you should not have "raw pointers" as members. State your intent : who own's what, if you want to use pointers use std::unique_ptr or std::shared_ptr! Or in this case just make your member array a std::vector<double> and you get complete default and correct copy behavior for free.

Comment: *I am not quite sure how this could have happened.* -- The other tip is to not write so much code before you even know if the basics work correctly.  Why are you involving `initializer_list` constructors, when the basic copy operations are faulty?  The class should have had one pointer, one "size" member, a "regular" constructor that populates the data, copy constructor, assignment operator, and destructor.  Nothing more than that -- then test to make sure the class has correct copy semantics *before* writing any other code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is the misuse of the `std::memcpy` function:

`std::memcpy(&data, &(v.data), v.elements);`

Since `data` and `v.data` are already pointers to the data, getting the address of those pointers results in the incorrect pointer values being used for those arguments.

The other issue is that the third argument `v.elements` should denote the number of *bytes*, not the number of elements, to copy.

The correct call to `std::memcpy` should have been:

`std::memcpy(data, v.data, v.elements * sizeof(double));`

---

But having said all this, do not use `std::memcpy`, and instead use `std::copy`.  That will work with the number of elements, plus can work with types that are not trivially-copyable (such as `std::string`):

```
#include <algorithm>
//...
std::copy(v.data, v.data + v.elements, data);
```

Comment: Hi PaulMcKenzie, Thanks for the reply. Yes, the issue is with the `std::memcpy`. I performed an element-wise copy using a for loop and it worked as well. And I tried `std::memcpy` and `std::copy`  suggested by you and it worked. May I know whether `std::copy` is the recommended way to use in modern C++?

Comment: Use `std::copy`, as a compiler will (should) default to use `memcpy` for trivial types like `double`.  So you aren't gaining anything by explicitly calling `memcpy`, and only potentially causing mistakes (such as what you were encountering).  Use `memcpy` for those situations where you are forced to do so, such as copying from one buffer to another, and the source and destination are of different types.